# Unable to fix java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for a shortest path problem

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to develop a **for cycle** to define a **sequence of actions** based on the **lower cost**.

To do that, I have defined an **actions array**. My idea is to **compare** each action in the array with another one, finding the cheaper path. When it's decided an action, after it's **removed**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        LinkedList list = new LinkedList(); 

        Action load_truck = new Action("load_truck","a","a","a", 4);
        Action load_plane = new Action("load_plane","a","a","a", 1);
        Action fly = new Action("fly","a","a","a", 2);
        Action drive = new Action("drive","a","a","a", 5);
        Action unload_truck = new Action("unload_truck","a","a","a", 6);
        Action unload_plane = new Action("unload_plane","a","a","a", 3);

        Action acts[] = {load_truck, load_plane, fly, drive, unload_truck, unload_plane};

        State state = new State(0);

        System.out.println(acts[2].g); // this is a control to check if code is working until here



        for(int i = 0, j = 0; acts.length > 0; i++, j++) {

        if(acts[j].g >= acts[i].g) { // g is the cost, the last action parameter


            Node current_node = new Node(acts[i]);
            state.addState(1);


            List<Action> removeList = new ArrayList<Action>(Arrays.asList(acts));
            removeList.removeAll(Arrays.asList(i));
            acts = removeList.toArray(acts);




            System.out.println("The action is "+ " "+ acts[i].name + "  Array lenght is" + acts.length);

        }else {


            Node current_node = new Node(acts[j]);
            state.addState(1);


            List<Action> removeList = new ArrayList<Action>(Arrays.asList(acts));
            removeList.removeAll(Arrays.asList(j));
            acts = removeList.toArray(acts);


            System.out.println("The action is" + " "+ acts[j].name + "  Array lenght is" + acts.length);

        }

    }
```

When I run my code I obtain this result

```
2
The action is  unload_plane  Array lenght is6
The action is  unload_plane  Array lenght is6
The action is  unload_plane  Array lenght is6
The action is  unload_plane  Array lenght is6
The action is  unload_plane  Array lenght is6
The action is  unload_plane  Array lenght is6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at linkList.LinkedList.main(LinkedList.java:105)
```

So I think that the problem is where I remove the action for each loop, because seems not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: Your j and i will always be the same.

Comment: And how can I fix it?

Comment: A) you have to really understand what your algorithm is supposed to do B) you have to debug why it is getting in such an "error" condition ... and unrelated: please read about java naming conventions. You dont use "_" in normal variable names, instead, you go camelCase in Java.

Comment: And that exception means: you are using an invalid index on an array. Part of your homework is to **find out** how to do things properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To begin with, change `removeList.removeAll(Arrays.asList(i))` to
>   `removeList.remove(i)`  or
>   `removeList.remove(Arrays.asList(acts).get(i))`. If you check the output,
>   your code is not removing the elements and that is the reason why the
>   length is printed as `6` every time.

Next Problem:

```
 for(int i = 0, j = 0; acts.length > 0; i++, j++)        
    if(acts[j].g >= acts[i].g)
```

The initial size of the array `acts` based on your cade is 6. But to make the explanation smaller, let's just consider the initial as 3 (like you have included only 3 actions to compare).

> What you want to do is compare each element with the other in array to
>   find the cheapest while removing an action with each iteration. Let's
>   see what's going wrong with your implementation.

Initial Size of Acts: 3

1. 1st iteration: acts size:3, i=0, j=0 --->`if(acts[j].g >= acts[i].g)` compares acts[0] with
   acts[0] which will always be equal and nothing is being removed like
   I explained above.
       Prints acts[0] and length is 3
2. 2nd iteration: acts size:2, i=1, j=1 --->`if(acts[j].g >= acts[i].g)` compares acts[1] with
   acts[1] which will always be equal and none removed.
       Prints acts[1] and array size is 3 again

> Before Proceeding, Think for a while what I am getting at? I bet you will figure it out otherwise well, continue reading :)

3. 3rd iteration: acts size:1, i=1, j=1 --->`if(acts[j].g >= acts[i].g)` compares acts[1] with
   acts[1] which will always be equal and array size reduces by 1 since
   you removed an action.
       Prints acts[3] and array size like you already guessed is 3

So, Now? We have already reached the last element in your array and the size has not reduced at all. Therefore, `acts.length > 0` will always be true (control will never exit for loop) and your array will go for another iteration.

- 4th iteration: acts size:1, i=4, j=4 ---> `if(acts[j].g >=acts[i].g)` 
  compares acts[4] with acts[4] and array does not have a
  4th element and it causes the famous `Array Index Out Of Bounds`
  exception because you are trying to access an index that does not
  exist. :)

Concluding: We now have the reason why it throws an error and yes, we also realized your 
          implementation is always comparing the values at any index to itself so 
         `if(acts[j].g >= acts[i].g)` will always be true which is a flaw in the code.